# Custom UL LI Select Box appears to be behind other HTML elements

Tags: html, css

I really need your help.

I can't seem to figure out as to why my custom UL LI select box appears behind other HTML elements. How do you fix it such that when the user clicks the select box, it will appear on top of the other page elements?

Here is a picture of the problem at hand:
[image]

Here is a pictured of the desired result:
[image]

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1a3ux8cw/4/

Here is the CSS in Question:

```
<style type="text/css">
* {
    font-family: Segoe UI;
    font-size: 9pt;
}
.select {
    background: url(arrow.png) no-repeat scroll right top;
    border: 1px solid rgb(170,170,170);
    width: 180px;
    padding: 3px;
    position: absolute;
}
.select:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    border-color: rgb(112,112,112);
}
.select ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    background: red;
}
.select ul li {
    display: none;
    padding: 1px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.select ul li:hover {
    background: rgb(112,146,190);
    color: #FFF;
}
.selected {
    background: rgb(195,195,195);
}
</style>
```

HTML:

```
Numbers<br>
<div class="select" id="numbers">&nbsp;
    <ul>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li data-val="1234">1234</li>
        <li data-val="5678">5678</li>
        <li data-val="9101">9101</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<br><br>
Letters<br>
<div class="select" id="letters">&nbsp;
    <ul>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li>abcd</li>
        <li>efgh</li>
        <li>ijkl</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<br><br>
Fruits<br>
<div class="select" id="fruits">&nbsp;
    <ul>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li>apples</li>
        <li>bananas</li>
        <li>oranges</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your Fiddle doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle doesn't work. It has errors. Plus, this seems to be a `z-index` issue on the `<ul>`. You need to give the `z-index` to both the `relative` and `absolute`ly positioned elements.

```
z-index: 999;
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is remove the absolute position from the select class, and the relative position from the select > ul. Since you are assigning those positions to those elements, that moves them to the top of the z-index stack.

The labels that are buried under those elements exist outside of those divs, or rather everything in those select class divs are absolutely positioned over them. You can remove those positions from the CSS and then a wrap the entire thing a div with a position of absolute. Then those all of your elements will be back in flow with each other.